# matlab deploytool giving the error when trying to build c++ shared library

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-deployment

Error: An error occurred while shelling out to mbuild (error code = 9).
Unable to build executable.

I don't know why I'm getting this error? and what to do with it? I've already installed a c++ compiler on my machine. I'm trying to build the c++ shared library of my Matlab code, i.e. convert my m-file to c++ code, so that I can use it in my c++ compiler, but while using deploytool, I'm getting this error. someone please help me. thanks in advance.
I'm using matlab r2009b and the compiler for c++ is dev cpp.

Comment: Try execute it with the verbose option enabled. It might reveal the problem. Try also to run mex -setup and have Matlab reconfigure environment variables

Answer (score 1):

Run `mbuild -setup` to select the compiler you have installed. Also make sure it is one of the supported ones [from the mathworks website](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2009b/).